# Integer range based specialization of template method in template class

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Is there any way to do a range specialize of template function in an integer template class? After a lot of research I get the feeling that the answer might be simply "no", but maybe there is a neat trick or workaround.

I simplyfied my class as much as possible to demonstrate the problem.

```
template<int value>
class MyClass
{
    template <typename T, typename X>
    uint64_t foo()
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Unsupported type combination.");
        return 0;
    }

    uint64_t m_member;
};
```

Very easy so far. The non-specialized implementation uses a static assertion, because I only want the template function to be used for certain types. These functions are specialized outside the class definition.

```
template<>
template<>
uint64_t MyClass<1>::foo<uint8_t, uint16_t>()
{
    return m_member * 1000;
}

template<>
template<>
uint64_t MyClass<7>::foo<uint8_t, uint16_t>()
{
    return m_member * 7000;
}
```

No I am looking for a solution to use this specialization for a certain range of val. I want MyClass<0> to throw the static assertion, MyClass<1>, MyClass<2>, ... , MyClass<6> should use MyClass<1> and finally MyClass<7> has to use the second specialization. Other specializations of *foo* work different. I have plenty of functions like *foo* and all do have about 10 type combinations working and all of them work very different.

The easiest workaround would be to simply duplicate the specializations, but I hope for a better solution. It would be nice if *foo* can be kept as a template function, but I also could live with a solution defining all possible combinations of *foo*, e.g. foo_u8_u16();, foo_u32_u64(), ...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What about stuff like `MyClass<1>::foo<int, double>();`? Do you intend to limit certain specializations of `MyClass` to only a single specialization of `foo`?

Comment: I do need stuff like MyClass<1>::foo<int, double>();. A limitation to a single specialization would mean, that I don't need a template class function at all.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you explicitly specialized `foo` in your example. So, just to confirm, should `MyClass<7>::foo<uint8_t, uint16_t>();` and `MyClass<7>::foo<int, double>()` do the same thing?

Comment: You questions are reasonable. I edited the question to make it more clear. Both specializations, if allowed, do different things. Probably it does not matter for a possible solution if foo is a template function or not. The key is the function specialization for the integer range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
template<int value, class T, class X>
struct Helper {
    static uint64_t foo(uint64_t param) {
        return Helper<value - 1, T, X>::foo(param);
    }
};

template<class T, class  X>
struct Helper<0, T, X> {
    static uint64_t foo(uint64_t param) {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Unsupported type combination.");
        return 0;
    }
};

template<>
uint64_t Helper<1, uint8_t, uint16_t>::foo(uint64_t param) {
    return param * 1000;
}

template<>
uint64_t Helper<7, uint8_t, uint16_t>::foo(uint64_t param) {
    return param * 7000;
}

template<int value>
class MyClass {
    template<class T, class X>
    uint64_t foo() {
        return Helper<value, T, X>::foo(m_member);
    }

    uint64_t m_member;
};
```

Comment: I just edited the question and added a member value. This can be simply passed as a parameter to the static version of foo. All in all, this solution looks very promising. I will try it out.

Comment: Yeah, that's a trivial change. I updated the answer for completeness.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

// the implementation of foo is moved to a different class

template<int value, typename = void>
struct FooImpl
{
    template <typename T, typename X>
    uint64_t foo()
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Unsupported type combination.");
        return 0;
    }
};

// partial specialization that will be enabled
// when value is in range [1,6)

template<int value>
    typename =  typename std::enable_if<value > 0 && value < 7>::type>
struct FooImpl<value,
        typename std::enable_if<(value > 0 && value < 7)>::type>
{
    template <typename T, typename X>
    uint64_t foo()
    {
        return 1000;
    }
    // you can write several overloads instead of a template, too
};

// now inherit from FooImpl

template<int value>
class MyClass : private FoomImpl<value>
{
    // write a forwarding function for foo here
    // or just a using declaration
};
```

Hope that helps and that I understood your question correctly.